# SYS.DBMS_INTERNAL_LOGSTDBY causes error on dump import

Tags: dump, oracle-xe

I'm having problems importing a dump into an Oracle XE Database.
The import worked for several other people, so I can assume that the dump is not corrupt.

In ran the following command:

> C:\Users\franzm>impdp abcac@xe DIRECTORY=exp_dir
>   DUMPFILE=expdp_abc_20140122010001.dmp schemas=abc LOGFILE=log.log

exp_dir was set before to the folder with the dump file

I'm getting the following error:

> ORA-31626: job does not exist ORA-04063: package body
>   "SYS.DBMS_INTERNAL_LOGSTDBY" has errors ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not
>   find program unit being called: "SYS.DBMS_INTERNAL_LOGSTDBY"
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 991 ORA-04063: package body
>   "SYS.DBMS_LOGREP_UTIL" has errors ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find
>   program unit being called: "SYS.DBMS_LOGREP_UTIL"

I searched the net and found some topics in the oracle board, but those didn't helped me.
Anyone has a hint?

Comment: Did you try logging in as SYSDBA and recompiling `SYS.DBMS_LOGREP_UTIL`? If that doesn't work, what errors does it give (`SHOW ERRORS` in SQL*Plus)?

Comment: http://navaneethdba.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/ora-04063-package-body.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Oracle XE did the job.